# Induction with summation

Tags: summation, induction

learning discrete math here. I know how to do simple induction with summation like

$\sum _{i=0}^k\:i^2$ and when it's $k+1$ u add whatever $\sum _{i=0}^k\:$ is with $(k+1)^2$
(sry, my explanation was terrible. hopefully, u understood)

I found some hard practice questions online and came across this question. No clue how to approach this question

> For all integer $m\ge 1$, use proof by *inducton* to show that:
> $$2m\left(\frac{4m+1}{3}\right)\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left(1^2+2^2+3^2+\:...\:+\left(2m\right)^2\right)$$

what I'm confused about is this: if I do k+1 here then it's not
$$[(1^2)+(2^2)+...+((2m)^2)+((2m)^2 +1)]$$
but it's rather
$$[(1^2)+(2^2)+...+((2m)^2)+...+(2(m+1))^2]$$

for example, if $m$ is $3$, then the end is $36^2$
and when $m$ is $4$, the end is $64^2$
so it's not the $1^2+2^2+...+36^2+37^2$ that I know

so completely lost as to how to start lol. I tried searching online for stuff like this and came up empty. any push in the right direction would be appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: It sounds like your struggle here is in interpreting the ellipses correctly.  This is again... $1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+(2m)^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2m} i^2$.  If we were to increment $m$ to the next value... this would have become $1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+(2(m+1))^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2(m+1)}i^2$ which of course you can siphon off the last two terms in the summation... here, $1^2+2^2+\dots+(2(m+1))^2 = \underbrace{1^2+2^2+\dots+(2m)^2}_{\text{should recognize}}+(2m+1)^2+(2(m+1))^2$

Comment: That said, rereading your post... it looks like you did understand it correctly but are maybe just lacking confidence in how to proceed?  The whole point in induction is to try to use what you already know to be true to prove more cases are true which in turn prove more cases and more cases and so on... like a line of dominoes having tipped over the one causes the rest in the line to fall down as well.

Comment: Let $f(m) = \frac{m(2m+1)(4m+1)}{3}$
Your goal is to show that $f(m+1) = f(m) + (2m+1)^2 + (2(m+1))^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah I understood the summation part. what I'm saying is that I know how to do questions like from $1^1+2^1+...+36^2$ to $1^1+2^1+...+36^2+37^2$, but not like to $1^1+2^1+...+36^2+...+64^2$

Comment: @okzoomer wouldn't it be f(m+1)=f(m)+(2m+1)^2+...+(2(m+1))^2? that's the part i'm confused about, how to do the '...' part lol

Comment: @CurryFlurry yes except $2(m+1)= 2m + 2$ so $(2(m+1))^2 = (2m+2)^2$ which is the next term after $(2m+1)^2$

Comment: If it went from $1^2+2^2+\dots+36^2$ to the "next" statement, that would go to $1^2+2^2+\dots+38^2$ which is as alluded to before recognizable as $\underbrace{1^2+2^2+\dots+36^2}_{\text{what we had earlier}}+37^2+38^2$

Comment: Like suppose $(2m)^2 = 36^2$ right? $2m = 36$ so $m = 18$. $18+1=19, (2(19))^2 = 38^2$ so from $36^2$ you just have to add $37^2$ and $38^2$

Comment: Here, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2(m+1)} i^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2m+2}i^2 = (2m+2)^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2m+1}i^2 = (2m+2)^2+(2m+1)^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{2m} i^2$

Comment: @okzoomer ah ok, so i plug in (m+1) in the left equation and make that equal to (2m+2)^2+(2m+1)^2+summation right?

Comment: @JMoravitz ah i c i c. thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: For every increase in $m$, you add two terms to the series. The first term is $(2m+1)^2$. The second is $(2m+2)^2$